# Changing URL and VirtualHost of Wordpress site

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, centos, virtual-host

I'll try to explain my situation.
I have 2 domains:

```
www.impiantisaettasnc.it
www.oasisgaming.it
```

and I want them to point on 2 different sites hosted on my VPS at `x.x.x.x` address.

So I went on my domains control panel, and I entered a DNS A record for my VPS's ip `x.x.x.x`.

Next I went on my server, and I made 2 separate virtualhost that look like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@impiantisaettasnc.it
    ServerName impiantisaettasnc.it
    ServerAlias www.impiantisaettasnc.it
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/impiantisaetta

# BEGIN WordPress
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
                RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php)?$ [OR]
                RewriteCond $1 \.(gif|jpg|png|ico|css|js)$ [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [S=1]
                RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/impiantisaetta/vhost-error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/impiantisaetta/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    # Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

one for each site, with right domain info in it.

Then I went on each wp-config file and appendend these 2 lines at the end:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.site1.it' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.site1.it' );
```

like I read on [official guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).
At this moment, domains are not showing correct sites, and I can't access my control panels in any way, neither from using my ip or the domain as url.

Also my `# apachectl -S` command output

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server impiantisaettasnc.it (/etc/httpd/conf.d/impiantisaettasnc.it.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost impiantisaettasnc.it (/etc/httpd/conf.d/impiantisaettasnc.it.conf:1)
                 alias www.impiantisaettasnc.it
         port 80 namevhost oasisgaming.it (/etc/httpd/conf.d/oasisgaming.it.conf:1)
                 alias www.oasisgaming.it
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html/main"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the database value by manually updating your phpmyadmin.

Other wise you can use the WP [Migrate DB plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) on your local work, then import the DB.

Sometimes the database value of the URL also causes the same issue.